# intercept and shortest distance bewteen 2 lines in 3D

Tags: computer-vision, computational-geometry

I would like to find the intercept of 2 lines in 3D. How can I check if they really intercept withour calculating the the real 3D coorindate at first. And then how can I calculate the 3D coordinates of that particular point?

Secondly, I understand it is not possible to find intercept points if two lines do not intercept. Thus, I would like to find a way to calculate 3d point which has the minimium distance from both point. I come with two minimium  distance requirements:
 1. take the shortest distance connecting two points and take the mid point as my result
 2. find the shortest perpendicular distance away from both lines

Would anyone can give me some tips on it?

Comment: I guess that 1. and 2. are identical.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After I think of it, they are equvialent .

Answer (score 1):

Let the first line be `P+u.U` and the second `Q+v.V`, where uppercase letters are 3D vectors.

You want to minimize the (squared) distance, i.e.

```
D²(u, v) = ((P+u.U) - (Q+v.V))²
```

Then, deriving on `u` and `v`, you get the system of equations

```
D²'u(u, v) = 2U.D(u, v) = 0
D²'v(u, v) = 2V.D(u, v) = 0
```

or

```
U.P + U².u - U.Q - U.V.v = 0
V.P + U.V.u - V.Q - V².v = 0
```

Solve this linear system of 2 equations in the 2 unknowns `u` and `v`, and from these, the closest points.

In the special case that the lines are parallel, the system determinant `U²V²-(U.V)²` is zero, as one expects (actually it is the square of the cross product `(UxV)²`). You can set `u=0` arbitrarily and solve for `v`.

Comment: Thank you very much. At the same time I alos find a source to the solution (Under topic "The shortest line between two lines in 3D")
[link](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/)